# difference between flip flops and latches

Tags: architecture, hardware

what is the difference between flip-flops and latches?

Comment: Actually not related to system administration in any way

Comment: Seems like we need an electronics/hardware based sister too.

Comment: If this question belongs on any one of the three sites, its SO (Its about programming http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_description_language).

Comment: Flip-Flops are a very basic type of footwear, while latches are a type of door or window fastener.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article on the flip-flop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) has a good introduction. In particular, it notes that the distinction in terminology between "flip-flop" and "latch" is a recent distinction.

> In digital circuits, a flip-flop is a term referring to an electronic circuit (a bistable multivibrator) that has two stable states and thereby is capable of serving as one bit of memory. Today, the term flip-flop has come to mostly denote non-transparent (clocked or edge-triggered) devices, while the simpler transparent ones are often referred to as latches; however, as this distinction is quite new, the two words are sometimes used interchangeably (see history).

Comment: I learned the "previous" definition, luckily they wrote "recent distinction" so I can still deny that I'm old ;-).

Comment: I find that the terms often get used interchangeably, and people say flip flop when they're actually after a transparent latch, and vice versa.

Add to that the fact that what mos people consider a flip flop is also known as being a "D-Type Transparent Latch", and you're in one hell of a nomenclatural mess.

Answer (score 5):

An oft-made distinction is that a flip-flop has a clock signal and a latch does not. Note, however, that not all engineers will make such a distinction.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Wikipedia flip-flop page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)):

> Today, the term flip-flop has come to
>   mostly denote non-transparent (clocked
>   or edge-triggered) devices, while the
>   simpler transparent ones are often
>   referred to as latches; however, as
>   this distinction is quite new, the two
>   words are sometimes used
>   interchangeably (see history).

In other words, you may find some people distinguishing between the two and others not...

Answer (score 1):

Flip flops have two values, while latches have one value.

Answer (score 0):

Flip flop is the general term for a bistable device.
The D-flip flop has a clock input and a data input and is the one that is called latch.

Answer (score 0):

Flip Flops are 1 bit storage devices.
The combination of flip flops are latches.

Answer (score 0):

Flip flops have three inputs typically labeled P Q and clock in, which SR latches have just S and r inputs. SR latches decide their logic based on high and low voltages of the s and r inputs. Flip flops rely on the "rising edge" clock cycles and then the value of P's and Q's to determine the next value. Both are 1 bit storage devices obviously. The truth tables for both logic devices are relatively similar

Answer (score 0):

A latch will pass the value through until latched (an input, level based) where it holds that latched value and does not allow the input through to the output.  When unlatched (the latch input changes to the unlatched state) it returns to allowing the value through.

A flip flop is a bit, it holds a zero or one, you set it or clear it, it can be clocked or not, non clocking has two inputs a reset input and a set input.  Edge based.  A clocked flip flop has a data input and a clock.  On the edge of the clock it will latch the input value for the duration of the clock cycle (clock on and off) until the next asserting clock edge, so it is not quite like a latch which only holds the value for one level of the input but similar.  If the non-data input of a latch was fed a clock it would only latch the value for half the clock cycle not the whole clock cycle like a flip flop would.

Answer (score 0):

flip-flops has a clock, latches are not have.